# More than one type at once in JSON-LD notation

Tags: microdata, linked-data, structured-data, json-ld

Is it valid by format conventions to use more then one type in JSON-LD notation? Like here:

```
{
 "@context":    "http://schema.org",
 "@type":
     [
     "MusicalEvent",
     "CreativeWork"
     ],
 "name": "Name",
 "url": "http://example.com"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly valid to use more than one type. If it makes sense, they don't even need to be from the same vocabulary (e.g. schema:Person and foaf:Person).

Comment: thank you! I just got some doubts with a case, when such 2-types notation gets more then one name attribute and the values will be different. So i guess it must be no problem too: the crawler will simply get the both to know and there isn't a question about respecting one value and no respecting the second